Need to get the head guesture from the gyrometer values and accelerometer values from the IMU sensor
I am getting ABS_X ,ABS_Y and ABS_Z vales of gyrometer and accelerometer respectively
I am confused about this equation could you please explain how u will do the calculation if I give the below as sensor info...
Gyro Data:
Event: time 1685442192.074233, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.084194, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1 Event: time 1685442192.084194, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 164 Event: time 1685442192.084194, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 9 Event: time 1685442192.084194, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.094199, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 2 Event: time 1685442192.094199, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 165 Event: time 1685442192.094199, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 11 Event: time 1685442192.094199, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.104178, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 10 Event: time 1685442192.104178, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 164 Event: time 1685442192.104178, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 9 Event: time 1685442192.104178, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.114221, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 9 Event: time 1685442192.114221, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 172 Event: time 1685442192.114221, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 8 Event: time 1685442192.114221, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.124197, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1 Event: time 1685442192.124197, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 183 Event: time 1685442192.124197, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 10 Event: time 1685442192.124197, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.154216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 13 Event: time 1685442192.154216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 194 Event: time 1685442192.154216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 12 Event: time 1685442192.154216, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.164185, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 7 Event: time 1685442192.164185, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 199 Event: time 1685442192.164185, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 18 Event: time 1685442192.164185, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.174190, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 10 Event: time 1685442192.174190, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 205 Event: time 1685442192.174190, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 10 Event: time 1685442192.174190, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442192.184210, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 5 Event: time 1685442192.184210, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 211 Event: time 1685442192.184210, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 11 Event: time 1685442192.184210, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Accelero Data: vent: time 1685442458.934261, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442458.944228, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4100 Event: time 1685442458.944228, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -923 Event: time 1685442458.944228, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16880 Event: time 1685442458.944228, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442458.954216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4227 Event: time 1685442458.954216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -1014 Event: time 1685442458.954216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16523 Event: time 1685442458.954216, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442458.964213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4059 Event: time 1685442458.964213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -1013 Event: time 1685442458.964213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16765 Event: time 1685442458.964213, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442458.974258, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4081 Event: time 1685442458.974258, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -955 Event: time 1685442458.974258, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16758 Event: time 1685442458.974258, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442458.984215, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4165 Event: time 1685442458.984215, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -986 Event: time 1685442458.984215, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16851 Event: time 1685442458.984215, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442458.994212, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4234 Event: time 1685442458.994212, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -1052 Event: time 1685442458.994212, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16732 Event: time 1685442458.994212, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442459.004246, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4135 Event: time 1685442459.004246, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -987 Event: time 1685442459.004246, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16642 Event: time 1685442459.004246, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442459.014217, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -3962 Event: time 1685442459.014217, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -1003 Event: time 1685442459.014217, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16631 Event: time 1685442459.014217, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------ Event: time 1685442459.024205, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value -4025 Event: time 1685442459.024205, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value -1134 Event: time 1685442459.024205, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 16379 Event: time 1685442459.024205, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
angle = 0.98*(angle + gyroDatadt) + 0.02accAngle ---> I got this from online web
Could you please explain how the above formula can i use it and how to find the angle?

why no body answering

no body knows this one?
